# Creating R Sequence for 4 numbers increasing consecutively from different starting points

Tags: r, sequence

I am experienced in R, however have little to no experience in sequences.

I would like to make a sequence of numbers where the first 4 numbers are starting points, and increase consecutively. Namely:

```
5,72,144,210,[now I repeat each +1], 6,73,145,211,[and so on],7,74,146,212
```

Hence:

```
c(5,72,144,210,6,73,145,211,7,74,146,212..)
```

Would greatly appreciate any ideas on how to set this up. I would for example need this to continue on for 60 iterations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
x <- c(5,72,144,210)
rep(x, 60) + rep(0:59, each=length(x))
```

Or making use of R recycling as mentioned by Ronak Shah:

```
x + rep(0:59, each=length(x))
```

Or:

```
as.vector(do.call(rbind, lapply(c(5,72,144,210), function(k) k:(k+60))))
```

output:

```
  [1]   5  72 144 210   6  73 145 211   7  74 146 212   8  75 147 213   9  76 148 214  10  77 149 215
 [25]  11  78 150 216  12  79 151 217  13  80 152 218  14  81 153 219  15  82 154 220  16  83 155 221
 [49]  17  84 156 222  18  85 157 223  19  86 158 224  20  87 159 225  21  88 160 226  22  89 161 227
 [73]  23  90 162 228  24  91 163 229  25  92 164 230  26  93 165 231  27  94 166 232  28  95 167 233
 [97]  29  96 168 234  30  97 169 235  31  98 170 236  32  99 171 237  33 100 172 238  34 101 173 239
[121]  35 102 174 240  36 103 175 241  37 104 176 242  38 105 177 243  39 106 178 244  40 107 179 245
[145]  41 108 180 246  42 109 181 247  43 110 182 248  44 111 183 249  45 112 184 250  46 113 185 251
[169]  47 114 186 252  48 115 187 253  49 116 188 254  50 117 189 255  51 118 190 256  52 119 191 257
[193]  53 120 192 258  54 121 193 259  55 122 194 260  56 123 195 261  57 124 196 262  58 125 197 263
[217]  59 126 198 264  60 127 199 265  61 128 200 266  62 129 201 267  63 130 202 268  64 131 203 269
```

Comment: Thank you! This is excellent. Would you happen to know how to make the output separated by commas in the form of c(1,2,3,5, etc)?

Comment: do you mean `dput` into a R structure? or into a string using `paste(..., collapse=", ")`?

Comment: I think the latter- as some context, what I want to do is re-arrange columns so I need this output in the form of df_sub <- df[,c(1,2,3,4)], but with the list of column names based on the sequence above

Comment: then you will need `dput` and not a string

Comment: you can make this a little shorter/faster by removing the `rep` for `x` as it would recycle the values. `x + rep(0:59, each = length(x))`